# R package leaflet popup on hover

Tags: javascript, r, leaflet

In R, I would like to create a popup when hovering over a polyline that has been added to a leaflet map.

Below is some code to create three random polylines on a map.

```
library(leaflet)
library(dplyr)
m = leaflet() %>% addTiles()
rand_lng = function(n = 10) {rnorm(n, -93.65, .01)}
rand_lat = function(n = 10) {rnorm(n, 42.0285, .01)}
m %>% addPolylines(
  c(rand_lng(10), NA, rand_lng(10), NA, rand_lng(10)),
  c(rand_lat(10), NA, rand_lat(10), NA, rand_lat(10)),
  color = c('red', 'green', 'blue'),
  fill=FALSE, weight=2
)
```

I would like a different popup to occur when hovering over each of the lines.

The `options` argument looks useful, especially combined with `popupOptions()` but I don't see much on the hover options, and do not quite not how to integrate it.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this problem?

Comment: @jalapic, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30964020/popup-when-hover-with-leaflet-in-r/36984950#36984950 for an alternative solution to a similar problem