# R and Leaflet: How to arrange label text across multiple lines

Tags: r, leaflet

Suppose you have the following data frame:

```
cities = data.frame( name = c('Madrid','Barcelona','Sevilla'),
                 country = c('Spain','Spain','Spain'),
                 region = c('Comunidad de Madrid','Cataluña','Andalucia'),
                 data = c(100, 200, 300), 
                 lng = c(-3.683333,2.166667,-6.083333),
                 lat = c(40.433333,41.383333,37.446667))
```

My idea is to have a map of these cities and labels that could display some relevant information when hovering the corresponding city circles. I'd like to have the label text arranged in several lines. The very first approach below failed:

```
library( leaflet )

map = leaflet( cities ) %>%
addTiles() %>%
addCircles( lng = ~lng, lat = ~lat, fillColor = 'darkBlue', radius = 10000, 
          stroke = FALSE, fillOpacity = 0.8, label = paste0( cities$name,'\n', cities$region, '\n', cities$country, '\n', cities$data ) )
```

as well as other similar attempts. After googling a while, I found a possible solution by involving the *htmltools* package:

```
library( htmltools )
map2 = leaflet( cities ) %>%
addTiles() %>%
addCircles( lng = ~lng, lat = ~lat, fillColor = 'darkBlue', radius = 10000, 
          stroke = FALSE, fillOpacity = 0.8, 
          label = HTML( paste0( '<p>', cities$name, '<p></p>', cities$region, ', ', cities$country,'</p><p>', cities$data, '</p>' ) ) )
```

In this case, the information is displayed as I'd like but, within the same label, there is an entry for each city of the dataset. How could I do to have the text of a single city arranged in multiple lines? Any help would be really appreciated

Answer (score 54, accepted):

First, create a character vector of html content for each city and then wrap that in a `lapply` call to set the `HTML` attribute for correct display when defining the `label` attribute in `adCircles`

```
labs <- lapply(seq(nrow(cities)), function(i) {
  paste0( '<p>', cities[i, "name"], '<p></p>', 
          cities[i, "region"], ', ', 
          cities[i, "country"],'</p><p>', 
          cities[i, "data"], '</p>' ) 
})

map2 = leaflet( cities ) %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addCircles(lng = ~lng, lat = ~lat, fillColor = 'darkBlue', radius = 10000, 
              stroke = FALSE, fillOpacity = 0.8,
              label = lapply(labs, htmltools::HTML))

map2
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was searching for and looks so simple and obvious that it should have come to my mind by myself. Just a minor adjustment to your code the last ')' is not required. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the hint with the bracket... Copy&paste error

Comment: in 2019, if `labs` is already a column in `cities`, you can continue to use the `~` pattern `addCircles(label = ~HTML(labs), ...)`, also `paste(sep = <br/>, ...)` is an alternative label building pattern for multiliners (https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet)/popups.html)

Comment: @Nate, your link is broken - can you fix? Tks!

Comment: Non-broken link to the [documentation website for popup](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/popups.html). Thanks @Nova! (sorry can't edit previous comment due to age)

Comment: @Nate's comment really helped me. I didn't want spaces between separate lines in  my label, and `<br/>` was the answer (instead of `<p>` and `</p>`).

Answer (score 5):

The following also works for two labels:

```
labels <- sprintf(
  "<strong>%s</strong><br/>%g people / mi<sup>2</sup>",
  states$name, states$density
) %>% lapply(htmltools::HTML)

m <- m %>% addPolygons(
  fillColor = ~pal(density),
  label = labels,
  labelOptions = labelOptions(
    style = list("font-weight" = "normal", padding = "3px 8px"),
    textsize = "15px",
    direction = "auto"))

m
```

see [here](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/choropleths.html) for further info.

p.s: I wanted to use it for three labels but couldn't manage to.

Answer (score 2):

@goodyonsen More labels can be added, for example you wanted 3 labels, in this case add an extra break and adequate specifier (e.g. %g).
In your code, to turn it into 3 labels (adding another character string -name- for the sake of example), you can do :

```
labels <- sprintf(
  "<strong>%s</strong><br/>%g people / mi<sup>2</sup><br/>%s",
  states$name, states$density, states$name
) %>% lapply(htmltools::HTML)
```

[r](/questions/tagged/r) [leaflet](/questions/tagged/leaflet)